# Table Layout Alignment?

Tags: android, image, button, android-tablelayout

I have designed an XML layout as in this image:

[image: the four buttons in table layout]

I need to equally place the four buttons in the screen but I am having trouble getting it to work. I tried all possible changes that I can think of. Below is the layout's XML:

```
<RelativeLayout  
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
   android:layout_height="40dp" 
   android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
   android:layout_alignBottom="@id/framelayout">


<TableLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TableRow>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/previous"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/previous_icon" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_startprint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/print_icon"
    android:padding="10dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_cam"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/cam_icon"
    android:padding="10dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/next_icon"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"/>

 </TableRow>  
 </TableLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: hi @ jxgn you want to do it in Vertically ????

Comment: hi @ jxgn i have added the code in edit .. check it out .. hope it will help you .

Comment: yeah i already changed :) it worked but the images look stretched :(

Comment: hi i have added the new code in below as the new answer.. now it wont get stretched..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi  jxgn use this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/previous"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_startprint"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_cam"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `android:layout_weight=1`, and Use `android:layout_width="0dp"` to make buttons of equal weights..

**EDIT** 
for example define your button as

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_cam"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=1
        android:background="@drawable/cam_icon"
        android:padding="10dp" />
```

Comment: thanks :) but the images gets stretched. is there anything i can do for that??

Answer (score 1):

If you set the attribute android:weight="1" for all four buttons they should be spaced out properly as TableRow is a subclass of LinearLayout. For better performance it is suggested to use android:layout_width="0dp" as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace all your buttons width with `layout_width="0dp"` and add `layout_weight="1"`

Try to use 9-patch image to avoid the fact that your image get stretched

```
  <TableRow>

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/previous"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_compass"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_startprint"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_mylocation"
        android:padding="10dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_cam"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_mapmode"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_about"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

 </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set at each button:

```
android:layout_weight="0.25"
```

Hope this will already work for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this it is usefull

```
  <RelativeLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"     >


<TableLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TableRow>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/previous"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"  
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_startprint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_cam"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    android:layout_weight="1"     />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    android:layout_weight="1"       />

  </TableRow>  
  </TableLayout> 
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying `android:layout_weight="1"` in your xml will stretch your button images.

If you dont want to stretch button images use `ImageButton` and set `android:src` to your drawables.

Refer below code:

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/previous"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/previous_icon"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_startprint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/print_icon"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_cam"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/cam_icon"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/next_icon"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

`